# To do list using react is not working, unable to split logic using custom hooks and multiple compontents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, refactoring

I am trying to split my code for a to do list into diferent components, it was working before i split it up, but after its not working. i am also trying to separate the logic into a custom hook and maybe that is where the problem is, but can find why its not working.

Can some help me on this and explain me the best practice to structure components, and custom hooks to keep the code easy to read and simple?

I want to make the code as easy to ready as possible, and maintainable using the best practices.

here is the code:

**App component**

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import Form from './components/Form'
    import List from './components/List'
    import useGrocery from './hooks/useGrocery'

    function App() {

  
      return (
       <section className='section-center'>
          <Form />
          <List/>
       </section>
      )
    }
    export default App
```

**form component,containts the form to enter every new item**

```js
    import useGrocery from "../hooks/useGrocery"
    import Alert from "./Alert"

    const Form=()=>{

   const { itemText, setItemText,isModifying, handleSubmit } = useGrocery()
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Grocery Bud</h2>
        {alert.type && <Alert /*{...alert} setAlert={setAlert}*/></Alert>}
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='form-control'>
         <input type='text' className='grocery' placeholder='e.g.eggs' name='inputItem' value={itemText} onChange=.       {(e)=>setItemText(e.currentTarget.value)} autoFocus ></input>
         <button type='submit' className='submit-btn'>
          {isModifying?'Edit':'Submit'}
         </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
}
export default Form
```

**List component, shows the list of items**

```js
import useGrocery from '../hooks/useGrocery'
import ItemList from './ItemList'
const List=()=>{
  
  const { items, removeItem, modifyItems,clearAllItems } = useGrocery()

    return (
        <>
        {items.length>0 && 
            <section className='grocery-container'>
              {items.map((item,index)=>{
                return <ItemList  key={index} newItem={item} index={index} FnRemoveItems={removeItem} FnModifyItems={modifyItems} />
              })}
              <button type='button' className='clear-btn' onClick={clearAllItems}>Clear all items</button>
            </section>
        }
        </>
    )
}
export default List
```

**custom hook with all logic**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { FaEdit, FaTrash } from 'react-icons/fa'
const ItemList = ({newItem,FnRemoveItems,FnModifyItems,index}) => {

return <article className='grocery-item'>
    <h3>{newItem}</h3>
    <div className='form-control'>
     <FaEdit className='edit-btn' onClick={()=>FnModifyItems(newItem,index)}/>
     <FaTrash className='delete-btn' onClick={()=>FnRemoveItems(newItem)}/>
    </div>
  </article>
}

export default ItemList
```

**every item of the list component.**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { FaEdit, FaTrash } from 'react-icons/fa'
const ItemList = ({newItem,FnRemoveItems,FnModifyItems,index}) => {

return <article className='grocery-item'>
    <h3>{newItem}</h3>
    <div className='form-control'>
     <FaEdit className='edit-btn' onClick={()=>FnModifyItems(newItem,index)}/>
     <FaTrash className='delete-btn' onClick={()=>FnRemoveItems(newItem)}/>
    </div>
  </article>
}

export default ItemList
```

**alert component**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import useGrocery from '../hooks/useGrocery'

const Alert = () => {
const {alert,setAlert}=useGrocery()
const {alertState,type,message} =alert

useEffect(()=>{

const alert= setTimeout(()=>{
setAlert({alertState:false,type:'',message:''})
    },3000)
return ()=>{
clearTimeout(alert)
    }
  },[alertState])
return <p className={`${type} alert` }>{message}</p>
}

export default Alert
```

Comment: You duplicated your code snippets, the hook is missing from your question.